# Extract id value from css class to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul menu from which I want to retrieve certain information:

```
<ul id="form_builder_sortable" class="sortable rightDiv session1">
    <li class="draggable ui-state-highlight item id10" name="Maths">Maths<button onclick="deleteElement(event)" class="delbtn">&times</button></li>
</ul>
```

I have a function in javascript:

```
function getSessionDatas()
{
    var sessions = [];
    $('.rightDiv').each(function(index)
    {
        var session = $.trim($(this).text().slice(0, -1)).split("×");
        var sessionData = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < session.length; i++)
        {
            var s = {
                subjectOrder: i,
                subjectID: subs[session[i]]
            };
            sessionData.push(s);
        }
        var ses = {
            sessionNo: index,
            sessionData: sessionData
        };
        sessions.push(ses);
    });
}
```

Here:

```
var s = {subjectOrder:i, subjectID:<get id here>};
```

I want to assign the subject id according to the class of the `<li>` item, in this case in the class there is an `id10`. How can I assign the `subjectID` to 10 in this case?

Comment: Will there be multiple `li` in each `rightDiv`? Which id value will be assigned in that case?

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes, there will be multiple li, and the id value will be different. It is going to be the id of the subject in the database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `data-*` prefix custom attribute which can be retrieved using [`.data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)  method.

```js
$('.rightDiv li').each(function(index) {
  var id = $(this).data('id')
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="form_builder_sortable" class="sortable rightDiv session1" >
  <li data-id="10" class="draggable ui-state-highlight item" name="Maths">Maths<button onclick="deleteElement(event)" class="delbtn">&times</button></li>
  <li data-id="11" class="draggable ui-state-highlight item" name="Maths">English<button onclick="deleteElement(event)" class="delbtn">&times</button></li>
</ul>
```

for those not using jQuery, same can be fetched using [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

```
var id = this.dataset.id;
```

Comment: @DaniM Will each li have a different id value?  If so, add the `data-id` attribute to the li instead of the ul and this will work (in principle - just a minor change).

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't a particularly good approach, it is possible to retrieve a specific class-name from an element's classes, so long as you can predict a particular pattern. In this case, for example, that the required class-name begins with the string of `id`:

```
// elem:   a single node reference, the element from which
//         you want to retrieve a specific class-name;
// prefix: String, the string with which the required
//         class-name(s) begins.
function retrieveClassByPrefix(elem, prefix) {

  // either elem, or prefix, are undefined or otherwise
  // falsey we quit here:
  if (!elem || !prefix) {
    return false;
  }

  // otherwise we convert the classList of the element into
  // an Array, using Array.from() on the result returned from
  // elem.classList, and then use Array.prototype.filter()
  // to filter the Array:
  return allClasses = Array.from(elem.classList).filter(

    // currentClass - using an Arrow function - is a reference
    // to the current class-name of the Array of class-names over
    // which we're iterating; if the currentClass String begins
    // with the supplied String ('prefix') then that class-name
    // is retained in the Array:
    currentClass => currentClass.startsWith(prefix)
  );

}

let idClassName = retrieveClassByPrefix(
  document.querySelector('#form_builder_sortable > li:first-child'), 'id'
);
```

Comment: Thank you David for the time you put to this one. I accepted an answer above as it is easier for me to understand, thanks again!

Comment: I think it should be `document.querySelector('#form_builder_sortable > li:first-child'), 'id'` (minor syntax error)

Comment: @Satpal: you're absolutely right (of course); thanks, that's what comes of answering via phone... >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can get the classes of your li element, and find which one match with idXX

```
var regexId = /id([0-9]+)/gi
$('.rightDiv').each(function( index ) {
 //do some stuff
  $(this).find("li").each(function(){
      var classes = $(this).classes.split(/\s+/); // get the classes in an array
      for(var c in classes){
        c = classes[c]; //one classe
        var regexExec = regexId.exec(c);
        if(regexExec  && regexExec.length > 1){
                var id = regexExec[1];
               //do your stuff with the id 
               break;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I had to accept another answer, but this is really good as well :)